# Import error with django_cups

Tags: django

I am using `django_cups` in my project, and I am getting import error in the models line 4.   [Here is the `models.py` file](http://code.google.com/p/django-cups/source/browse/trunk/django_cups/models.py?spec=svn2&r=2)

```
python ./manage.py runserver

...
File "/home/lex/myapp/django_cups/models.py", line 4, in <module>
import cups
ImportError: No module named cups
```

I have `django_cups` installed because when I `import cups` in the python shell it doesn't complain.

```
lex@lex-pc:~/django/mykapp$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:32:33) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cups
>>> 
>>>
```

But when I do it in the InteractiveConsole for Django, it complains...

```
(env)lex@lex-pc:~/django/myapp$ python ./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:32:33) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import cups
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cups
>>>
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Most likely the package was installed outside the `env` environment; try installing it inside.

Comment: it is already in python, how do I get it in the env?

Comment: Recreate the environment with `virtualenv --system-site-packages` if you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual environment, by default, does not include the system packages. To use both system and local packages, use [`virtualenv --system-site-packages`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#the-system-site-packages-option) when creating the environment.